# Does Facebook mobile app login return the Facebook profile id (and email address)?

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, facebook-login

I want to allow users to login via Facebook within my Android app.
I then match that Facebook login to an account with the Facebook profile Id in my database, which I've stored if the user has already logged in before via my website in his desktop browser.

So if the user logs in via my app, I potentially need to match that with an existing record in my DB based on the user.

I'm reading this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

However, I'm not sure if via this login button it's possible to retrieve the Facebook profile Id (AND preferably also the email address) of the user that logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get both.

The ID that you will receive will be an *app scoped user id*. That means that every App-User combination results in a different (and unique) ID. Stated otherwise; if you have multiple apps in your database, you can't just link every new user to an existing one. For that use case there is the [Business Mappping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business). This basically is a system when you register all the apps you own, and then you can map the different IDs. But; in the simple use case, of just one app, you always get an ID. But, this is not the normal Facebook ID (and there is no way of retrieving that).

You can get this by using [the current profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#track_profile). This will give you an [Profile object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/), which has basic info like *id, firstName, lastName, name*.

To get the email address of the user you need to request the [email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-email), which you can request from you app without needing to submit for review. When this permission is granted, you can [fetch user data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata-step3) using your app.

Please keep in mind that not all users have an email address and others might not give you the permission to retrieve it. So the App-Scoped User ID is the most reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will get the required. You can access the graph API so you can get all data for which you have permission to access